# After system restore to factory settings: Unable to convert OEM partition to system partition

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I have Windows 8 on my computer. I restored my Windows 8 to factory settings. My OS partition and another partition are o.k., but one partition became an OEM partition. Can someone tell me how I can restore that partition?

Comment: Are you trying to recover the data from the lost partition?  What was the partition originally?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if it is OEM partition, you can change that as any other partition. I use "Easus Partition Master" to manage my partitions.
I don't really know exactly if this is the answer you are looking for.